# Can a Git reference repository be created for a local repository?

Tags: git

I have access to a Git repository over NFS but the clones I'm making are on a different mount so I can't create hard links to it. I'd rather not do a full clone since it takes a lot of time and disk space. Can I use a reference clone? It seems strange since the reference repository is the same as the target.

```
git clone --reference=/path/to/repo /path/to/repo
```

Comment: What's wrong with a symlink instead of a hard link?

Answer (score 0):

You could do operations elsewhere while specifying the working tree and/or the git repo itself (the `.git`)

```
git --work-tree=/path/to/repo --git-dir=/path/to/repo/.git xxxx
```